# Why doesn't the same generated assembler code lead to the same output?

Tags: c, floating-point, x86-64, floating-accuracy, icc

Sample code (`t0.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float f(float a, float b, float c) __attribute__((noinline));
float f(float a, float b, float c)
{
    return a * c + b * c;
}

int main(void)
{
    void* p = V;
    printf("%a\n", f(4476.0f, 20439.0f, 4915.0f));
    return 0;
}
```

Invocation & execution (via godbolt.org):

```
# icc 2021.1.2 on Linux on x86-64
$ icc t0.c -fp-model=fast -O3 -DV=f
0x1.d32322p+26
$ icc t0.c -fp-model=fast -O3 -DV=0
0x1.d32324p+26
```

Generated assembler code is the same: https://godbolt.org/z/osra5jfYY.

Why doesn't the same generated assembler code lead to the same output?

Why does `void* p = f;` matter?

Comment: What in tarnation... are you sure the executables are identical? What does `diff` say?

Comment: I haven't yet compared executables. As I understand, godbolt.org doesn't (yet) allow to download (or compare online) the executables.

Comment: Use  the debugger - step over the assembly code. See what registers **really** contain before the call to `printf` depending on the other initialization code you do not see here. Fast math often gives "interesting" results because of that.

Comment: Yeah, I would wonder whether the assembly shown actually matches the code being executed.  For instance, maybe link-time optimization is happening?

Comment: Ah, check out when you select "Compile to binary". The `-DV=0` version has reduced `f` to just returning a constant - presumably interprocedural constant propagation, done once the linker can see there are no other calls to `f`.  Taking the address of `f` probably fools it.

Comment: Umm....what is 'V'?

Comment: @Martin: `V` is defined as a macro in the compile command.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh..ah... thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Godbolt shows you the assembly emitted by running the compiler with `-S`.   But in this case, that's not the code that actually gets run, because further optimizations can be done at link time.

Try checking the "Compile to binary" box instead (https://godbolt.org/z/ETznv9qP4), which will actually compile and link the binary and then disassemble it.  We see that in your `-DV=f` version, the code for `f` is:

```
 addss  xmm0,xmm1
 mulss  xmm0,xmm2
 ret
```

just as before.  But with `-DV=0`, we have:

```
 movss  xmm0,DWORD PTR [rip+0x2d88]
 ret
```

So `f` has been converted to a function which simply returns a constant loaded from memory.  At link time, the compiler was able to see that `f` was only ever called with a particular set of constant arguments, and so it could perform interprocedural constant propagation and have `f` merely return the precomputed result.

Having an additional reference to `f` evidently defeats this.  Probably the compiler or linker sees that `f` had its address taken, and didn't notice that nothing was ever done with the address.  So it assumes that `f` might be called elsewhere in the program, and therefore it has to emit code that would give the correct result for arbitrary arguments.

As to why the results are different: The precomputation is done strictly, evaluating both `a*c` and `b*c` as `float` and then adding them.  So its result of `122457232` is the "right" one by the rules of C, and it is also what you get when compiling with `-O0` or `-fp-model=strict`.  The runtime version has been optimized to `(a+b)*c`, which is actually more accurate because it avoids an extra rounding; it yields `122457224`, which is closer to the exact value of `122457225`.

Comment: Constant propagation might have been done with `double`, introducing two separate rounding steps, perhaps?  No, that wouldn't explain it; as doubles those operations are all exact since the numbers aren't too large.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sorted it out.  The constant-propagated version evaluates `(a*c)+(b*c)` strictly, incurring all the rounding errors in doing all operations as `float`.  The runtime version optimizes to `(a+b)*c` which is faster and more accurate but not strictly correct by C evaluation rules.  It looks like icc effectively does `-ffast-math` by default.

Comment: Yes, it does somewhat (default is `-fp-model fast=1`), although the Godbolt link in the question used `-fp-model=fast` (i.e. fast=2) to make it about as aggressive as GCC `-ffast-math`.  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html.  I'm not clear on exactly what is/isn't allowed at the default `fast=1`, but FP associative math assumptions are so it can auto-vectorize and look good when people benchmark it. (And distributive)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ah, okay, and `-fp-model=strict` gets us back to the strict version.  (Amusingly, before I checked the docs, my first guess was to do `-fp-model fast=0` and that ICEs: https://godbolt.org/z/YW96vYKj9)

Comment: Re: _but not strictly correct by C evaluation rules_: then `__STDC_IEC_559__` cannot be `1` ([as it is now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70115688/why-dont-non-strict-floating-point-models-change-the-value-1-of-stdc-iec-559)).

Comment: @pmor: Welllll... in the fine print, the ICC manual does say that [`-fp-model=precise` (which `=strict` implies) is required for "strict ANSI conformance"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html).  As such, `icc` *without* this option is not claiming to be a conforming implementation, and therefore nobody can stop them from defining any macros they like.

Comment: FYI: MSVC has [the similar scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170): _`__STDC__` defined as 1 only when compiled as C and if the `/Za` compiler option is specified. Otherwise, undefined._

Comment: Can you answer the prev. mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70115688/why-dont-non-strict-floating-point-models-change-the-value-1-of-stdc-iec-559): "not claiming ..., and therefore nobody can stop ..."?